# Retrofit enqueue methods not being called

Tags: android, callback, retrofit2

Im making an asynchronous call and im able to send a request to the server and getting my desired JSON(using postman) but for some reason the OnResponse and OnFailure methods are not being executed, may you please help me if im missing out something.Im using retrofit2

```
private List<Advert> getAdverts(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl( "http://192.168.100.4:8092/portal/")
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestService requestService = retrofit.create(RequestService.class);

    Call<List<Advert>> customerCall= requestService.getAdverts(accountNumber);
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++ request was made +++++++++++++++++++");


    customerCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Advert>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Advert>> call, Response<List<Advert>> response) {
            Log.d("onResponse", "" + response.message());

            System.out.println("++++++++++++++ was here+++++++++++++++++++");

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                adverts.addAll(response.body());

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Advert>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });

    return adverts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you're returning before de operation has ended (as you mentioned is a asynchronous call). So as soon you enqueue, you're returning "adverts" (probably cancelling your call).

Consider using other alternatives to return your response, like Callbacks, EventBus, persist the response on local storage, etc.

Comment: I just changed the return type of my method to void, so that I dont have to return anything,  still no luck

Comment: Yeah, lately I have been sending some requests and they were working fine but I just dont know whats going on with this particular request

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: Its now working fine, I had another method was interfering with my request, once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dilonne, if you found a solution for your question, it would be great if you post it here.

Comment: How do you know another method is interfering? I am also having same problems. the enque methods invokes the call sometimes and unable to invoke other times. So please help me how it is always executed.

Comment: Another person here having the same issue.

Comment: At first the enqueue function is called but its body is not getting executed checked in debugger whereas after some time, the onResponse() gets called. Here, i think the body doestn gets executed because the request is currently in its on going stage and isnt completed. anyone any solution for this?